# What is the difference between a static bool and a private static bool in this class?

Tags: c#, .net

Consider the `OutputToConsole` boolean in the `class` below.

Is there any difference between the following two lines of code?

```
private static bool OutputToConsole = true;
```

```
static bool OutputToConsole = true;
```

They both appear to function the same.

---

```
class Debug
{
    private static bool OutputToConsole = true;

    public static void Log(string Type, string URL, StringBuilder Parameters)
    {
        Write(Type + ":" + new string(' ', 9 - Type.Length) + URL + " { " +
            Parameters.ToString() + " }");
    }

    public static void Log(string Data)
    {
        Write("Response: " + Data);
    }

    private static void Write(string Output)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(Output);
        if(OutputToConsole) Console.WriteLine(Output);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default access modifier of class members is `private` in C# so if you do not write anything (like `private`, `public`, `protected` or `internal`), it's 100% like if you wrote  `private`.

Comment: because for people who do not know what the default value is, private keyword helps a lot! no kidding, actually at least in C++, classes have private as default and structs have public as default. so you need the private to make private struct members and public to make public class members :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference. If no access modifier is explicitly set, the default is private.